# Ocaml lexer / parser rules

Tags: stream, ocaml, camlp4

I wrote a program in ocaml that given an infix expression like 1 + 2, outputs the prefix notation : + 1 2

My problem is I don't find a way to make a rules like : all value, operator and bracket should be always separated by at least one space: 1+ 1 would be wrong 1 + 1 ok. I would like to not use the ocamlp4 grammar.

here is the code:

```
open Genlex                                                                                                                                                               

type tree =
  | Leaf of string
  | Node of tree * string * tree

let my_lexer str =
  let kwds = ["("; ")"; "+"; "-"; "*"; "/"] in
    make_lexer kwds (Stream.of_string str)

let make_tree_from_stream stream =
  let op_parser operator_l higher_perm =
    let rec aux left higher_perm = parser
        [<'Kwd op when List.mem op operator_l; right = higher_perm; s >]
        -> aux (Node (left, op, right)) higher_perm s
      | [< >]
        -> left
    in
      parser [< left = higher_perm; s >]        -> aux left higher_perm s
  in
  let rec high_perm l = op_parser ["*"; "/"] brackets l
  and low_perm l = op_parser ["+"; "-"] high_perm l
  and brackets = parser
    | [< 'Kwd "("; e = low_perm; 'Kwd ")" >]    -> e
    | [< 'Ident n >]                            -> Leaf n
    | [< 'Int n >]                              -> Leaf (string_of_int n)
  in
    low_perm stream

let rec draw_tree = function
  | Leaf n              -> Printf.printf "%s" n
  | Node(fg, r, fd)     -> Printf.printf "(%s " (r);
      draw_tree fg;
      Printf.printf " ";
      draw_tree fd;
      Printf.printf ")"

let () =
  let line = read_line() in
    draw_tree (make_tree_from_stream (my_lexer line)); Printf.printf "\n"
```

Plus if you have some tips about the code or if you notice some error of prog style then I will appreciate that you let it me know. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Genlex` provides a ready-made lexer that respects OCaml's lexical convention, and in particular ignore the spaces in the positions you mention. I don't think you can implement what you want on top of it (it is not designed as a flexible solution, but a quick way to get a prototype working).

If you want to keep writing stream parsers, you could write your own lexer for it: define a `token` type, and lex a `char Stream.t` into a `token Stream.t`, which you can then parse as you wish. Otherwise, if you don't want to use Camlp4, you may want to try an LR parser generator, such as [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) (a better ocamlyacc).

Comment: Well I don't want to use ocamlp4 grammar because it's really scary. I'm really new with the ocaml's syntax/philosophy. When you say you could write your own lexer, you mean I should not use make_lexer and write my own function ? Thanks for helping !

Comment: Yes, if you want a fine-grained handling of whitespace, you should write your own lexer function. Genlex is only one particular instance of such a function. But have you considered using a parser-generator instead of writing one by hand?

Comment: Yes I have considered it but I wanted to feel confortable with ocamlp4's streams so I just wrote my own parser and I had in mind that it should be a good training.